# Python updated political map of India with state boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

Can anyone help me with plotting the most recent political map of India which also includes state boundaries?
The default maps in basemap or cartopy does not include the disputed areas and state boundaries.
My present code is

```
import cartopy as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree()))
ax.set_extent([67.0, 98.0, 5.0, 38.0])
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='gray', alpha=0.5,
                  linestyle='--')
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
ax.coastlines(color='black', linewidth=1, resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS.with_scale('10m'),
               linestyle='-', alpha=.5)
```

Comment: Apart from your link, if you want a proper map of India, with the borders of Jammu and Kashmir as the constitution states, you can try this link: http://www.indianremotesensing.com/2017/01/Download-India-shapefile-with-kashmir.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'),
               linestyle='-', alpha=.5, color='red')
```

to draw states boundaries, but this will draw all countries states.

[image]

Note: Strangely enough, when using scale '50m', only US, Brazil and Australia states are draw.

If you need country specific data, the best way is to download a shapefile from [GADM](https://www.gadm.org/data.html). After downloading and unzipping the India file, you can plot like this:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
ax.set_extent([67.0, 98.0, 5.0, 38.0])
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='gray', alpha=0.5,
                  linestyle='--')
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
ax.coastlines(color='black', linewidth=1, resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS.with_scale('50m'),
               linestyle='-', alpha=.5)

# ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'),
#                linestyle='-', alpha=.5, color='red')

fname = '/tmp/india/gadm36_IND_1.shp'
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(fname).geometries(),
                               ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='red')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)
```

[image]

_0 is country level, _1 is state level and so on. But I have no idea how disputed areas are presented.